# Fastest/One-liner way to conditionally remove multiple directories on Unix

Tags: unix, shell, command-line, conditional-statements

What is the shortest way I can write:

```
rm -rfv public/stylesheets public/images public/javascripts
```

and make it conditional, with something like:

```
if [ ! -d public/stylesheets ]; then rm -rfv public/stylesheets; fi ...
```

Just discovered/found a use for command-line conditionals :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in public/{stylesheet,image,javascript}s; do [ -d $i ] || rm -rfv $i; done
```